# QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: php, soap, web, quickbooks, connector

```
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'APPNAME' has STARTED
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: APPNAME
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): APPNAME
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: http://localhost/quickbooks/qbwc/qbwc.php
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.1.0.30">
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'APPNAME', username = 'Admin'
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="Admin"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/xml', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20150604.02:34:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

I've triple checked that the .qwc username is the same as it is in the quickbooks_user table and the password given in the connector matches as well.
The error message claims it's getting what is expected. Any help on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> The request failed with an empty response.

As with troubleshooting *any* PHP script, the very first thing you should do is check your PHP error log.

Did you check it? What did it say?

Failing that -- *post your code*. Tough to help you if you don't post your code so we can see what you're doing.

You could also use a test script that simulates a Web Connector session -- for example:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/dev/dev_qbwc_tester.php

From:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

That script will simulate a Web Connector session and show you the output from your PHP script.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this currently but it's happened to me multiple times in the past. My error log shows nothing of use (which just means I probably need to log the proper kinds of errors).
I'm marking this as answered once I can reproduce it and figure out what I was doing wrong for any future Googlers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It ended up being a connection string error. That's why the response was blank. Your comment was very helpful in figuring that out.